# Android : Custom ListView Disappear After Orientation Change

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-orientation

**PROBLEM**

I have created custom ListView which contains custom View, and some textViews per List Item.
Everything work as I expect until device orientation change, ListView disappear.
I know the issue happen when orientation change activity will recrate. But, I have already save necessary file in application as JSON String format and when activity recreate I found that data was load and run successfully till the end of the code no force close however, listview is not show?

**NOTE**

I'm sure that my save data is usable because this file is use for prevent fetching data from internet if available and I have test it already, it work!

my custom listview have listview class provide arraylist and adapter class, but I can't provide it here because it too long.

**MAIN CLASS**

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.schedule);

        aq = new AQuery(this);
        lvSchedule = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_schedule);
        scheduleLvItems = new ArrayList<Schedule_ListView>();
        dm = new DataManager(this);


        //check available in app data
        String scheduleJSON = dm.readFile("scheduleJSON");
        if (scheduleJSON != "empty"){
            System.out.println(scheduleJSON);
            renderData(scheduleJSON);
        }
        else{
            String url = "http://requestURL/getSchedule_v2.php?+" +
                    "loginId="+yourID+
                    "&password="+yourPassword+
                    "&year=2013&semester=2";

            aq.ajax(url,String.class, this,"cb1");
        }

    }


    public void cb1(String url, String html, AjaxStatus status){

        System.out.println(html);
        renderData(html);

    }

    public void renderData(String jsonString){

        try {

            List<List<String>> monData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            List<List<String>> tueData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            List<List<String>> wedData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            List<List<String>> thuData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            List<List<String>> friData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            List<List<String>> satData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            List<List<String>> sunData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

                        /*Note [Knowledge]
                        *JSON Symbol {,} = JSONObject
                        *JSON symbol [,] = JSONArray
                        */

            //Change JSONString to JSONArray
            JSONArray jsonArray_data = new JSONArray(jsonString);

            //Set jsonArray_data in global variable for further use
//            ((Global_Variable)getApplicationContext()).setJsonSubject(jsonArray_data);

            //Save Persistence Json Array in app data for fetch with out internet
            dm.writeFile("scheduleJSON",jsonArray_data.toString());

            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray_data.length(); i++){
                //Change object to String and stored each JSON item in Variable
                JSONObject dataRecord = jsonArray_data.getJSONObject(i);

                String      yearSemester    = dataRecord.getString("YEAR / SEM");
                String      courseID        = dataRecord.getString("COURSE ID");
                String      courseName      = dataRecord.getString("COURSE NAME");
                String      courseSection   = dataRecord.getString("SECTION");
                JSONArray   courseInfo      = dataRecord.getJSONArray("COURSE INFO");
                String      finalDate       = dataRecord.getString("FINAL DATE");
                String      finalRoom       = dataRecord.getString("FINAL ROOM");
                String      finalTime       = dataRecord.getString("FINAL TIME");
                String      midtermDate     = dataRecord.getString("MIDTERM DATE");
                String      midtermRoom     = dataRecord.getString("MIDTERM ROOM");
                String      midtermTime     = dataRecord.getString("MIDTERM TIME");
                int         subjectColor    = getResources().getColor(SUBJECT_COLOR[i]);

                for(int ii = 0; ii < courseInfo.length(); ii++){
                    //Change object to String and stored each JSON item in Variable
                    JSONObject infoRecord = courseInfo.getJSONObject(ii);

                    String day          =   infoRecord.getString("DAY").replace(".","").trim();
                    String tStart       =   infoRecord.getString("TIME").replace(" - ","").trim().substring(0,5);
                    String tStop        =   infoRecord.getString("TIME").replace(" - ","").trim().substring(5);
                    String roomStudy    =   infoRecord.getString("ROOM STUDY");
                    String instructor   =   infoRecord.getString("INSTRUCTOR");

                    List<String> dataRow = new ArrayList<String>();

                    if (day.contains("Mon")) {
                        dataRow.add(courseName);                    //course name
                        dataRow.add(tStart);                        //period start
                        dataRow.add(tStop);                         //period end
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(subjectColor));  //subject color
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(i));             //subject position in json
                        monData.add(dataRow);
                    } else if (day.contains("Tue")) {
                        dataRow.add(courseName);                    //course name
                        dataRow.add(tStart);                        //period start
                        dataRow.add(tStop);                         //period end
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(subjectColor));  //subject color
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(i));             //subject position in json
                        tueData.add(dataRow);
                    } else if (day.contains("Wed")) {
                        dataRow.add(courseName);                    //course name
                        dataRow.add(tStart);                        //period start
                        dataRow.add(tStop);                         //period end
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(subjectColor));  //subject color
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(i));             //subject position in json
                        wedData.add(dataRow);
                    } else if (day.contains("Thu")) {
                        dataRow.add(courseName);                    //course name
                        dataRow.add(tStart);                        //period start
                        dataRow.add(tStop);                         //period end
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(subjectColor));  //subject color
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(i));             //subject position in json
                        thuData.add(dataRow);
                    } else if (day.contains("Fri")) {
                        dataRow.add(courseName);                    //course name
                        dataRow.add(tStart);                        //period start
                        dataRow.add(tStop);                         //period end
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(subjectColor));  //subject color
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(i));             //subject position in json
                        friData.add(dataRow);
                    } else if (day.contains("Sat")) {
                        dataRow.add(courseName);                    //course name
                        dataRow.add(tStart);                        //period start
                        dataRow.add(tStop);                         //period end
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(subjectColor));  //subject color
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(i));             //subject position in json
                        satData.add(dataRow);
                    } else if (day.contains("Sun")){
                        dataRow.add(courseName);                    //course name
                        dataRow.add(tStart);                        //period start
                        dataRow.add(tStop);                         //period end
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(subjectColor));  //subject color
                        dataRow.add(String.valueOf(i));             //subject position in json
                        sunData.add(dataRow);
                    }
                }
            }

            if(monData.size() != 0){
                scheduleLvItems.add(new Schedule_ListView(
                        R.drawable.monday_mdpi,
                        monData,
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.COLLAPSED_HEIGHT_1)
                ));
            }
            if(tueData.size() != 0){
                scheduleLvItems.add(new Schedule_ListView(
                        R.drawable.tuesday_mdpi,
                        tueData,
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.COLLAPSED_HEIGHT_1)
                ));
            }
            if(wedData.size() != 0){
                scheduleLvItems.add(new Schedule_ListView(
                        R.drawable.wendesday_mdpi,
                        wedData,
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.COLLAPSED_HEIGHT_1)
                ));
            }
            if(thuData.size() != 0){
                scheduleLvItems.add(new Schedule_ListView(
                        R.drawable.thursday_mdpi,
                        thuData,
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.COLLAPSED_HEIGHT_1)
                ));
            }
            if(friData.size() != 0){
                scheduleLvItems.add(new Schedule_ListView(
                        R.drawable.friday_mdpi,
                        friData,
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.COLLAPSED_HEIGHT_1)
                ));
            }
            if(satData.size() != 0){
                scheduleLvItems.add(new Schedule_ListView(
                        R.drawable.saturday_mdpi,
                        satData,
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.COLLAPSED_HEIGHT_1)
                ));
            }
            if(sunData.size() != 0) {
                scheduleLvItems.add(new Schedule_ListView(
                        R.drawable.sunday_mdpi,
                        sunData,
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.COLLAPSED_HEIGHT_1)
                ));
            }

            //add padding top - bottom for listview
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header, null);
            lvSchedule.addFooterView(header, null, false);
            lvSchedule.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
            //setup listView Adapter
            scheduleAdapter = new Schedule_Adapter(Schedule.this, R.layout.schedule_listview, scheduleLvItems);
            //setup adapter to listView
            lvSchedule.setAdapter(scheduleAdapter);
            //setup OnClickListener
            lvSchedule.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    int postion = i - lvSchedule.getHeaderViewsCount();
                    toggle(view, postion);
                }
            });

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your distributing the data to the `ListView` in onCreate and whenever you change the orientation, the activity will be restarted and the onCreate won't be called. Thus, it won't be distributed. to tackle this issue, just move this line and the related lines to `onResume`

```
renderData(scheduleJSON); //take more important lines with it to onResume
```

it should be like the following:

```
protected void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
   renderData(scheduleJSON); //take more important lines with it to onResume
}
```

**Second Solution:**

you can prevent the restart of the activity when orientation has changed by adding this to your manifest in the activity tag

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"> //this line
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I use your first solution. it works like a charm!

Comment: However, I have addition question.I put Toast.makeTake in onCreate() but as you said onRestart won't call onCreate() why it toast message out after orientation change which is in onCreate()